# Retrieving tree node text in KendoUI/Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

The objective of [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZQCCxpxeqbUNhqQTY8n?p=preview) is to query a specific tree node (given its id stored in the variable `sk`) and show an alert with its text. Enter a number in the input field (the node `sk` value), click on the button and you should see an alert with the node text.

The `get` method and `hasChildren` in the hierarchical data source are not working, any ideas?

HTML:

```
 <div kendo-tree-view k-data-source="treeData"></div>  
 <br/><br/>
 <button ng-click="queryTree()">Get Text</button>
 <input ng-model="sk">
```

Javascript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.sk = 3;
  $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data: [
                { sk: 11, text: "Furniture", expanded:true, items: [
                    { sk: 2, text: "Tables & Chairs"},
                    { sk: 3, text: "Sofas" },
                    { sk: 4, text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                ] },
                { sk: 12, text: "Decor", expanded:true, items: [
                    { sk: 6, text: "Bed Linen" },
                    { sk: 7, text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                    { sk: 8, text: "Carpets" }
                ] }
            ],
            schema: {
              model: { 
                id: "sk",
                hasChildren: function(item) {
                        return item.sk > 10;
                      } 
              }
            }
        });


     $scope.queryTree = function(){

         $scope.treeData.fetch(function() {
               var dataItem = $scope.treeData.get($scope.sk);
               alert(dataItem.text); 
           });
      };

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the datasource directly:

```
$scope.queryTree = function(){
  var nodeDataItem = $scope.treeData.get($scope.sk);
  alert(nodeDataItem.text)
};
```

Here is a working plunkr for you. http://plnkr.co/edit/N4FYVh227HjvYOoWMYo4

Comment: This is not working for the children, also try expanding the tree that's not working either.

Comment: Check plunkr now, fixed children not expanding for you also.